# How to use Fluid template to translate content

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid

I made two files in one my extension and the directory is my_path/Resources/Private/Language. I have use this  and for the first time i have used source as search and target is suche it display but not for the source it directly displays the target but when i change the target its not displaying. So how i should proceed now.
If i write  then it directly give me the value not translating.so i want to be translated.

Comment: can you rephrase your question ? it is hard to understand what are you asking. Do you want to know how to get content from xml with translation ?

Comment: You need to clear the cache in the install tool in order to see changed localizations.

Comment: @Jost ya right.....And got the solution

Answer (score 0):

Didn't understand the question very much but did you used in viewhelper like this :

take a look at the documentation for localizing an extension maybe help :
http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/9-CrosscuttingConcerns/1-localizing-and-internationalizing-an-extension.html

Answer (score 0):

based on your question and answer in comment you're looking for `<f:translate />` ViewHelper